# MUI Version 4 Tabs Scroll Buttons Customization

Tags: button, material-ui, scroll

I'm using MUI Tabs to list the list of sections with MUI Version 4. I need both of the scroll buttons to be present in the right end of the tabs. I can't change the position of the scroll buttons in **ScrollButtons** Props. It only has 'on', 'off', 'auto' & 'desktop'.

[**Note:** The working of the scroll buttons should be same working as in the Google sheets]

How can I achieve this in MUI Version 4.